# Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=/processUafRequest.jspx on Android

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpclient

I got the exception when communicating with the api:

```
Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=/processUafRequest.jspx
```

My code :

```
// HttpClient creation part is omitted.
URI uri = new Uri("https://company.myserver.com/processUafRequest.jspx?param=tmp")
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
httpPost.setURI(uri);
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I looked it up and it says it's because I didn't add 'https', but I'm using it in my url.
Aside from that, in what cases does this exception occur?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use URIBuilder class and set host, scheme & path methods using setHost("www.myserver.com") , setScheme("https") & setPath("processUafRequest.jspx") methods.

Also your current code seems to be missing "www"

Comment: Would not using 'www' be a problem? My url is in the form "https://company.myserver.com"

Comment: It should work but then in the shared code you have not added "company"

Comment: I edited the code. Thanks for talking.